# What is wrong with this XPath Expression in a jaxb bindings file?

Tags: xpath, jaxb

trying to evaluate the XPath expression
    `/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='StrikeOptionReservationSummaryData']/xs:complexType`

with the following document produces an XPathExpressionException
    `<xs:schema>

        <xs:element name="StrikeOptionReservationSummaryData">

            <xs:complexType>

                ...

            </xs:complexType>

        </xs:element>

    <xs:schema>`

The error from from xjc is `[ERROR] XPath error: null`

What is wrong with this?

Comment: The XPath expression is fine, syntactically. Please provide more info on the error itself.

Comment: Eh... xs:complexElement != xs:complexType ?

Comment: Without the evaluation context, we can only guess. So, this is not a complete question. The easy guess is that it's missed/wrong the namespace URI binding. But there is already too much of this kind of questions here. So, this would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a lousy diagnostic, but perhaps you didn't give the XPath processor a binding for the namespace prefix "xs"?

Comment: making sure the xs prefix was mapped into the external .xjb customization file seems to eliminate the error... now I just have way more jaxb problems to solve.